# Unloading swf file through button click

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

So I'd like to set this up to where you click on a button it loads a new scene and unloads the previous scene.

This is what I have so far.

```
staart.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler);

function fl_MouseClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
function loadSWF(swfURL){
var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();
var mySWF:URLRequest = new URLRequest(swfURL);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener
(Event.COMPLETE,onCompleteHandler);
myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener
(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onProgressHandler);
myLoader.load(mySWF);

}

function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event){    
  addChild(loadEvent.currentTarget.content);
  loadEvent.currentTarget.content.gotoAndStop(swfFrame);
}

function onProgressHandler(myProgress:ProgressEvent){
var percent:Number = 
Math.round(myProgress.bytesLoaded/myProgress.bytesTotal*100);
trace(percent+"% loaded");
}


}
var swfFrame:Number= 1;
loadSWF("home.swf");
```

}

Is it possible to unload a specific swf file or previous swf file through a newly loaded swf file?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a variable for your swf.

Add this to your code :

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
// Adds the movie clip at initialization.
addChild(mc);
```

and modify your onCompleteHandler method like this :

```
function onCompleteHandler(loadEvent:Event){
  // Changes the content of your movie clip.
  mc = loadEvent.currentTarget.content;
  mc.gotoAndStop(swfFrame);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

shawn gave you the right answer but there are 2 other problems in your code:
There's a typo in element `staart` and a potential memory leak because you add event listeners without removing them. You should add the following two lines in `onCompleteListener` function:

```
loadEvent.currentTarget.removeEventListeners(Event.COMPLETE,onCompleteHandler)
loadEvent.currentTarget.removeEventListeners(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS,onProgressHandler)
```

If you don't remove the listeners, the garbage collector will be unable to free the memory of every loader you create on each click